# Groupby specific hour interval per day

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
df = 

                     val1     val2
date
----------------------------------
2021-06-01 00:00     1        3
2021-06-01 01:00     2        4
2021-06-01 02:00     3        5
2021-06-01 03:00     4        6
2021-06-01 04:00     5        7
2021-06-02 00:00     6        8
2021-06-02 01:00     7        9
2021-06-02 02:00     8        10
2021-06-02 03:00     9        11
2021-06-02 04:00     10       12
2021-06-03 00:00     11       13
2021-06-03 01:00     12       14
2021-06-03 02:00     13       15
2021-06-03 03:00     14       16
2021-06-03 04:00     15       17
```

If I then do something like:

```
df_new = df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
```

The resulting data frame will be:

```
df_new = 

                     val1     val2
date
----------------------------------
2021-06-01           3        5
2021-06-02           8        10
2021-06-03           13       15
```

However, I would like this to happen only for a specific time interval for each day. So in this case maybe only from `00:00-03:00` and not the `04:00` hour. Hence, the resulting data frame should instead be:

```
df_true = 

                     val1     val2
date
----------------------------------
2021-06-01           2.5      4.5
2021-06-02           7.5      9.5
2021-06-03           12.5     14.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) in `groupby` or [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df_new = df[df.index.hour < 4].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
df_new = df[df.index.hour < 4].resample('D').mean()
print (df_new)
            val1  val2
date                  
2021-06-01   2.5   4.5
2021-06-02   7.5   9.5
2021-06-03  12.5  14.5
```

Or use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df_new = df.between_time('0:00', '3:00').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
df_new = df.between_time('0:00', '3:00').resample('D').mean()
print (df_new)
            val1  val2
date                  
2021-06-01   2.5   4.5
2021-06-02   7.5   9.5
2021-06-03  12.5  14.5
```

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why I didn't think of that. But it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I like @jezrael's method better, but sticking close to your current code, you can do this:

```
m = (df.index.hour >=0) & (df.index.hour <= 3)
df[m].groupby(df[m].index.date).mean()
```

Output:

```
            val1  val2
2021-06-01   2.5   4.5
2021-06-02   7.5   9.5
2021-06-03  12.5  14.5
```